# Subscribe cloud pub/sub topic from app running on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, google-cloud-pubsub

I have created an pub/sub topic to which I will publish a message every time an new object is uploaded to the bucket. Now I want to create a subscription to push a notification to an endpoint every time a new object is uploaded to that bucket. Following the documentation, I wanted something like that:

`gcloud alpha pubsub subscriptions create orderComplete \
        --topic projects/PROJECT-ID/topics/TOPIC \
        --push-endpoint http://localhost:5000/ENDPOINT/
        --ack-deadline=60`

However my app is running on kubernetes and it seems that pub/sub cannot reach my endpoint. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As standing in [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push)

> In general, the push endpoint must be a publicly accessible HTTPS
>   server, presenting a valid SSL certificate signed by a certificate
>   authority and routable by DNS.

So you must expose your service via HTTPS using Ingress as described there:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress

Comment: I have created an ingress as mentioned on the the documentation, but I keep getting the following warning: `Some backend services are in UNKNOWN state`

Comment: Apparently there is something wrong at the edge of Ingress resource definition and Service. Can you post the output of:
"kubectl describe ingress <INGRESS_RESOURCE_NAME>"

Comment: I changed the workflow and following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#asynchronous-pull) I implement an asynchronous pull that is always listening for new objects on the bucket. Because as I understood even exposing my service using an ingress I would need to verify my domain to be able to push a notification to the endpoint, and I don't have a domain

Comment: `Annotations:
  ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy:     k8s-tp-default-my-echo-ingress--d1467ae955f13725
  ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map:          k8s-um-default-my-echo-ingress--d1467ae955f13725
  ingress.kubernetes.io/backends:         {"k8s-be-30870--d1467ae955f13725":"UNHEALTHY"}`

Answer (score 1):

In order for Cloud Pub/Sub to push messages to your application, you need to provide a publicly accessible endpoint. In Kubernetes, this most likely means exposing a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/). With this, you should have a non-local (i.e. no “localhost”) URL to reach the pods running your binaries.

Before creating the Cloud Pub/Sub subscription, you should also [verify your domain](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#domain_ownership_validation) with the Cloud Console.

Finally, you can set your subscription to push messages by [changing its configuration](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#subscriber-update-push-configuration-gcloud#change_pull_push):

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions modify-push-config mySubscription \
  --push-endpoint="https://publicly-available-domain.com/push-endpoint"
```

Comment: The problem is that I I don't have a domain

Comment: Pub/Sub requires a verified externally-accessible domain to push messages. If you host your server on [AppEngine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/writing-and-responding-to-pub-sub-messages), however, you could potentially use the *.appspot.com endpoint.

Alternatively, you can consume Pub/Sub messages via the Cloud Pub/Sub [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries), which use [Streaming Pull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull) to reach out to the service.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, so as @jakub-bujny points out you need a SSL endpoint. So one solution, on GKE, to use [google's managed certificates](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs) with an Ingress resource (link shows you how)